# Converting 2d String Array into a Map in Java8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

Seems like a very basic question, I want to convert my 2d string array into a `Map` with `List` as a Value.

I've tried something like below:

```
Map<String, List<String>> guestMap = Arrays
    .stream(guests)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e-> e[1], Collectors.toList()));
```

My nested array of strings like this

```
String[][] guests = {
    {"A", "lizzard"},
    {"B", "Gorilla"},
    {"C", "lizzard"},
    {"D", "Gorilla"},
    {"E", "lizzard"},
    {"F", "Gorilla"},
    {"G", "lizzard"},
    {"H", "Monkey"},
    {"I", "lizzard"}
};
```

I know about a way of solving it using `computeIfAbsent()`. But I'm looking for a solution purely using Stream API.

Comment: `List<String>` is the _value_ type of your map, not the key type. You'll want a downstream collector to be able to map to the appropriate outputs instead of your source objects (e.g. `"lizzard"` instead of `{"A", "lizzard"}`). Something akin to `Collectors.mapping(e -> e[0], Collectors.toList())` in place of your current `#toList` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since elements in the stream are of type `String[]`, with your current collector

```
Collectors.groupingBy(e-> e[1], Collectors.toList())
```

Map's Values would be of type `List<String[]>` (whilst you need a `List<String>`, not a list of arrays). Hence, you need to transform the stream elements received by the downstream Collector before storing them into a List.

As *@Rogue* has pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74865728/converting-2d-string-array-map-in-java8#comment132121548_74865728) you need to use Collector [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and the downstream of `groupingBy()`. And `toList()` should be in turn provided as the downstream Collector of `mapping()`.

```
String[][] guests = {
    {"A", "lizzard"},
    {"B", "Gorilla"},
    {"C", "lizzard"},
    {"D", "Gorilla"},
    {"E", "lizzard"},
    {"F", "Gorilla"},
    {"G", "lizzard"},
    {"H", "Monkey"},
    {"I", "lizzard"}
};
        
Map<String, List<String>> guestMap = Arrays.stream(guests)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e[1],
        Collectors.mapping(e -> e[0],
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
    
guestMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
Monkey -> [H]
lizzard -> [A, C, E, G, I]
Gorilla -> [B, D, F]
```